# Android app releases issue

Tags: android, release-management

Currently I have a hybrid app in the play store and recently I have developed a native app for that, by improving and adding more functions.

So I would like to roll out that as next update

I have following issues in mind:

- Do I have to sign this using the new app with same key-store file?
- Do I have to use same package name?
- Will changing version number be enough?

After little search I found out the procedure to release an app by 
[Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html) but it doesn't address my doubts so can someone explain the procedure to how to release the app and clear my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find my answers below:

> do i have to sign this using the new app with same key-store file ?

```
Yes, if you want to publish update of existing app, won't allow you to publish if different key-store used
```

> do i have to use same package name ?

```
Yes, if you want to publish update of existing app, will be considered new app otherwise
```

> will changing version number enough ?

```
Yes but version number should be greater than the version number of existing app
```

Comment: thank you @user12345 for clearing my doubts but doing only these 3 will be enough  ? i already changed  in manifest to old package name signed it using da same key file ,changed the version number to 2.0 if i upload this as a release will this replace the existing app without a issue ??

Comment: Thank you verymuch for responses @user12345

Answer (score 3):

Just change the version number to +1 and use same package google play store will take this apk .but you have to declare target version and compiled version same or updated.

> If you have same key and package name is same play store will take your Apk.
>   update your version number and put target and build version same or latest.

Comment: Thank you @android_jain and i did all mentioned before do i have to change build info also ?